# What fonts can I use to watermark my photos which come preinstalled with Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, licensing, watermark

I am looking for some fonts that I can use to watermark my photos. I don't want to install third part fonts (since I will be getting others to use them on various systems) so I'd like to use a font which everyone will have ready access to across various systems.

I can't find a list of fonts installed with Lightroom (on macOS). Two fonts I know that seem to come installed with Lightroom are Adobe Clean and Myriad Pro Web. I know that Adobe Clean [is not a "publicly available font"](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8872529) and can't be used in a watermark. I also know that Myriad Pro Web seems to come with Lightroom, but it of course seems to be something used only for the web and most likely needs to be bought as well to use.

What fonts can I use to watermark my photos which come preinstalled with Lightroom?

Comment: Other people will be watermarking your photos on different systems?

Comment: Why not use one of the many fonts that come with your operating system?

Comment: @Corey we are a group of photographers and would like to use the same font in order to keep the look consistent across out photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two fonts you mention that "come with Lightroom" are probably intended for use by Lightroom for its displays, and not installed as system fonts. I wouldn't expect *any* fonts to come preinstalled with Lightroom for use by you, there's just no reason to provide fonts with it.

Also, unless you can find a document telling you you have the right to use that font for your own work, you wouldn't be allowed to use any such bundled font for your work (same copyright rules as for images: just you having an image from someone else does not allow you to publish it)

But there are many fonts available which you can legally download and use. Have a look at e.g. [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/).

About the "others to use them on various systems":

- if the "them" refers to your watermarked photos, you can use any font you want (and for which you have the proper licence), others will not be able to access the fonts through your    watermarked images, as the few characters you have used are now    pixels in the image and not a font.
- if the "them" refers to the fonts, you'll have to install those on the various systems according to the license of the font.

Comment: I'm pretty sure s/he means fonts that come preinstalled with Adobe CC (for example, Minion Pro)

Comment: And unless the license allows differently, those *cannot* legally be used to watermark the photos... And might not be accessible directly from Lightroom or any other Adobe CC product (as they are not installed system-wide)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Something you mentioned confused me though... as far as I understand, you said I need the right to use the font in your second paragraph, but then in the second to last paragraph you said that I can use any font I want. That seemed contradictory, at least how I understood it. Could you kindly clarify on that point?

Comment: You need the right to use the font with which you watermark, but anyone using the images will not have access to the font. Edited the answer